# Two (in my opinion) equivalent SQL queries return different results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this query which returns the (correct) result in the screenshot below:

```
SELECT owner_id, MAX(ctime) as post_time, aid
FROM `jul_cpg15x_pictures`
GROUP BY aid
ORDER BY aid DESC
```

[image: Result of Query 1]

But I need the query in the following format (because I want to make some joins afterwards):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT owner_id, MAX(ctime) as post_time, aid
FROM `jul_cpg15x_pictures`
GROUP BY aid
ORDER BY aid DESC) q
```

This query returns a different result (some owner_ids are different):
[image: Result of Query 2]

This is driving me crazy for hours now, how can that be?
I double checked that the ctime is distinct in the table and does not occur twice. But for example for the ctime 1410003221 there is definitely only one entry (the one with owner_id = 8).

Thank you so much for any help or hints.

Comment: OWNER_ID is in your SELECT list but is not in the GROUP BY clause, despite using an aggregate function in the SELECT list.

Comment: If you select a column that isn't grouped by, you just get a random value from that group. Most databases other than MySQL would consider this SQL an error.

Comment: Do you want the highest post time (ctime) for each AID or each OWNER_ID and AID combination ??

Comment: I'm bookmarking this question just to slap in the face of people defending MySQL's idiotic behaviour concerning incomplete GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: Sorry, I really feel a bit stupid. @Brian DeMilia: I want the highest post time for each AID and the corresponding OWNER_ID.

Comment: @user1974951 no problem, I think I get what you want, just posted an answer based on that grouping, hopefully we are on the same page. You have to join into an inline view if I understand your intention correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT owner_id, MAX(ctime) as post_time, aid
FROM `jul_cpg15x_pictures`
GROUP BY aid
ORDER BY aid DESC
```

Uses a *partial group by*. You are selecting unaggregated values of `owner_id` and `aid` columns, but you are grouping only by `aid`. MySQL is free to return *any* `owner_id` for a given `aid` group. the `ORDER BY` clause does not help since ordering is performed *after* grouping.

So, if your data looks like:

```
owner_id  ctime       aid
--------  ----------  ---
8         1410003221  176
2         1410000000  176
```

Then both results are *correct* (both rows collapsed into one because of same aid, max ctime calculated as expected but owner_id from either row could be returned):

```
owner_id  post_time   aid
--------  ----------  ---
8         1410003221  176
```

```
owner_id  post_time   aid
--------  ----------  ---
2         1410003221  176
```

---

Having said all that, if your intention is to grab the `owner_id` of latest post for a given `aid` you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT s1.aid, s1.ctime, s1.owner_id
FROM jul_cpg15x_pictures s1
JOIN (
    SELECT aid, MAX(ctime) AS ctime
    FROM jul_cpg15x_pictures
    GROUP BY aid
) AS s2 ON s1.aid = s2.aid AND s1.ctime = s2.ctime
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. I have MAX(ctime) in my query, should the result not then be unique?
The query should (in my opinton) group by aid and take the largest corresponding ctime and the owner_id that corresponds to this ctime. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Query is asking to (i) group the results by aid (ii) then return MAX(ctime) for each group; it does not mention which owner_id (min, max or concatenated) from each group is to be returned.

Comment: I haven't heard the term "partial group by".  This is a MySQL extension that the documentation explicitly warns against using:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. I think I have understood the problem. But what I still don't understand is: Why does my first query then return the correct result? Is this only an incident or is there another explanation? Thx again!!

Comment: By the way, I have enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in my MySQL config file, now I get for both my original queries the following error: #1055 - owner_id isn't in GROUP BY :-)

Comment: @Fabi: (i) as mentioned in the answer, all results are _technically_ correct. If you get the _expected_ result then it is a coincidence. Add a couple of indexes, re-arrange the rows in the data, introduce a JOIN, etc and the results could change (ii) that is the right thing to do. Use the revised query (or Brian's one) which should work in any standard database.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, you can add more columns from the table if needed:

```
select t.owner_id, t.aid, t.ctime
  from jul_cpg15x_pictures t
  join (select aid, max(ctime) as last_post_time,
          from jul_cpg15x_pictures
         group by aid) v
    on t.aid = v.aid
   and t.ctime = v.last_post_time
 order by t.aid desc
```

As you indicated was your intention, per your comments, this query will show the last post_time for each aid, and then the corresponding owner_id.